# tfs 2013 export history from query

Tags: export

With TFS 2013, I've exported some queries to Excel. The "History" column is always blank, but I have confirmed that the work items have history entries.

How can I export so I can actually view the history?

Answer (score 1):

The History field isn’t a supported work item field in Excel.

> When Team Foundation publishes work terms to Office Project, the field
>   data is copies from the work item database to Office Project. For the
>   field data to be copied correctly, the field type in the work item
>   database, and the field type in Office Project must be compatible. The
>   History, Html and PlainText work item field types are not supported.